# how to group by a list of tuples using the inex

Tags: python, python-3.x

so here is my question,
the original sentence is s= 'this is awesome', if I use ASCII to translate it,

```
s='this is awesome'
s1= s.split(' ')
q=[]
p=[]
for i in s1:
    for j,m in enumerate(i):
        m=ord(m)
        q.append(m)
        p.append(j)

    final =zip(p,q)
f=list(final)
```

then I get a list of tuples

```
[(0, 116),
 (1, 104),
 (2, 105),
 (3, 115),
 (0, 105),
 (1, 115),
 (0, 97),
 (1, 119),
 (2, 101),
 (3, 115),
 (4, 111),
 (5, 109),
 (6, 101)]
```

however, what I really want to see is

```
this ==> change to ==>[116,104,105,115]
is==>change to ==>[105,115]
awesome==> change to ==>[97,119,101,115,111,109,101]
```

but I really need to have index here because later I will need to 
have the index + ASCII number to make it a new list.
Can anyone help?
thanks!

Comment: By index you mean index of the words or the characters of each word?

Comment: @HenryYik yes, the index of each letter as I show in the list

Comment: Cant understand your question! What exactly you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dictionary comprehension

**Ex.**

```
s='this is awesome'

data = {x:idx for idx,x in enumerate(s.split())}
output = {k:[ord(el) for idx, el in enumerate(k)] for k,v in data.items()}
print(output)
```

**O/P:**

```
{'this': [116, 104, 105, 115], 'is': [105, 115], 'awesome': [97, 119, 101, 

115, 111, 109, 101]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='this is awesome'
s1= s.split(' ')
q=[]
for i in s1:
    p=[]
    for m in i:
        m=ord(m)
        p.append(m)
    q.append(p)
```

output: q will be a list of list, such that inner lists are the representation of your words and for the index of letters in words use the index of inner list. Hope it works if not let me know.